# Spring BootでのInjectionについて

Tags: spring

Springで作成したソースを、Spring Bootで動作させるための作業を行っています。

下記のようなソースがあった場合、Springではapplication-config.xmlに、

```
<beans>
    <bean id="testService" class="test.service.impl.TestServiceAImpl" />
</beans>
```

と、記述して利用するクラスを決定していましたが、Spring Bootの場合はどのように設定すれば良いのか分かりませんでした。
application.propertiesに何らかの記述を行うことで、クラスを決定できればと思いますが、どのような記述が必要でしょうか？
よろしくお願いします。

> test.controller
>   　　└TestController.java 
>    test.service
>   　　└TestService.java (インターフェイス)
>   test.service.impl
>   　　└TestServiceAImpl.java　（TestServiceインターフェイス実装クラスＡ)
>   　　└TestServiceBImpl.java　（TestServiceインターフェイス実装クラスＢ)

TestController.java抜粋

```
@Autowired
private TestService testService;
```

---

コメントだけではフォローしきれませんでしたので、コメントを受けて修正したコードを記載します。
クラス構成及びTestController.java、TestService.javaには変更がありません。

TestServiceAImpl.java抜粋

```
@Service　　//@Componentの方が良い？
@Profile("TestServiceA")　　// 追加
public class TestServiceAImpl implements TestService
```

TestServiceBImpl.java抜粋

```
@Service　　//@Componentの方が良い？
@Profile("TestServiceB")　　// 追加
public class TestServiceBImpl implements TestService
```

application.properties抜粋

```
spring.profiles.active=TestServiceA　　// 追加
```

上記で、当初期待していた挙動を得ることができました、コメント頂ありがとうございます。

なお、コメント頂いたとおりConfigurationクラスを追加することも検討しましたが、その場合ConfigurationクラスのtestServiceA（spring.profiles.active=Aとした場合）、TestServiceAImpl、TestServiceBImplを候補としてNoUniqueBeanDefinitionExceptionがスローされてしまったため、上記の通りとなりました。

Answer (score 1):

```
@Configuration
public class AppConfig {
  @Bean TestService testService() {
    return new TestServiceImpl();
  }
}
```

なクラスをコンポーネントスキャン配下においてください。メソッド名がbean idになります

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
無事動作させることができました。

ただ、DIに必要な情報がConfigurationクラスとはいえ、コンパイルが必要なところにあるところにちょっと違和感を感じるところです。

Comment: `@Component`とか`@Service`とかをクラスにつけるのもConfigurationですし、慣れの問題だと思います。

もちろん潔癖にXMLだけで定義して、JavaのクラスにはConfigurationから完全に取り除くことも可能ですが、それが受けいれられなかったのがJavaの歴史ですので・・

ところで、`TestServiceA`と`TestServiceB`を切り替える方法を示していませんでしたが、こちらは大丈夫でしょうか？

Comment: @Configuration
    public class AppConfig {
      @Bean TestService testServiceA() {
        return new TestServiceAImpl();
      }

      @Bean TestService testService() {
        return new TestServiceBImpl();
      }
    }
    
    
と定義して、インジェクションする側に`@Qualifier`で名前をつければよいです。


    @Controller
    public class AaaController {
      @Autowired @Qualifier("testServiceA") TestService testServiceA;
      @Autowired @Qualifier("testServiceB") TestService testServiceB;
    }

Comment: `application.properries`でAかBかを切り替えたいのであれば、


  @Configuration
  public class AppConfig {

    @Profile("A")
    @Bean TestService testServiceA() {
      return new TestServiceAImpl();
    }

    @Profile("B")
    @Bean TestService testService() {
      return new TestServiceBImpl();
    }
  }

と定義して、`application.properties`で


    spring.profiles.active=A

とすれば、


    @Controller
    public class AaaController {
      @Autowired TestService testService;
    }

でインジェクションされるのは`TestServiceAImpl`になります。

Comment: フォローいただきありがとうございます。
最初の回答を見て、Configurationクラス内でServiceのインスタンスをnewしていたので、単純にnewするクラスを変更して対応する物なのかと考えました。